# What are on each of the faces of the dice in the US version of Yu-Gi-Oh! Dungeon Dice Monsters?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-dungeon-dice-monsters

*[Yu-Gi-Oh! Dungeon Dice Monsters](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5502/yu-gi-oh-dungeon-dice-monsters)* was a spinoff of the popular trading card game, which used the same iconic monsters, but instead was a tactical miniatures game featuring dice. The Japanese versions and the American version differed in the dice that were offered:

- In the Japanese version, you could snap together squares to create the six-sided dice with whatever combination of faces you wanted (Six Level 4 Summoning crests? Go for it!)
- In the American version, the dice were all premade and non-customaizable, coming in four different colors with each color apparently having in a different combination of faces

I'm trying to reconstruct the game, but don't have the dice from the American set. What are on each of the faces of the different dice? I've seen [a few images on BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5502/yu-gi-oh-dungeon-dice-monsters/images), but so far can't tell what is on all of the faces of the American dice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are on each of the faces of the different dice?

I found this [Dungeon Dice Monsters](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Crest_(Dungeon_Dice_Monsters)) page on the Wiki. There, it is specified each of the possible symbols and their meaning. The specific term used in the game is 'Crest', and you roll the dice to gather specific kinds of Crests to interact with the game.

*Edit*: I also found the [official ruling](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/43575.pdf) in case it helps as reference.

Worth mentioning that there are 4 kinds of dice, one for each possible monster level (1-4). Each dice has faces depending on the level they are (usually, the higher the level the less Summon Crests on the dice).

To summarize it here, the possible Crests are:

- **Summon Crest** (star symbol): These crests are used to summon monsters. There are 4 kinds of monster levels, and thus Summon Crests for each level. The higher the level the harder is to achieve a summon. This is because Lvl 1 dice have 4 sides with Summon Crests, but Lvl 4 dice only has 1 side with Summon Crest.
- **Attack Crest** (swords symbol): This Crest enables summoned monsters to attack. You need one Crest per attack, and a monster can only attack once per turn.
- **Defense Crest** (shield symbol): This Crest helps monsters to defend themselves from attacks. Basically, the Defense Crest subtracts Attack from the attacking monster and then calculation proceeds.
- **Trap Crest** (umbrella corp-ish symbol): Used to activate some monsters' effects when attacked.
- **Spell Crest** (thunder symbol): Similar to Trap Crests, these are used to activate monsters' abilities.
- **Movement Crest** (arrow symbol): Used to move your monsters across the board. One Movement Crests can move a monster one square (unless it is a Flying monster, which use 2 per square).

Regarding the content of the dice faces. On [this](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Dungeon_Dice_Monsters) wiki page we have, emphasis mine:

> No matter what version is played, the amount of summon crests is the same for all dice across a given level. **Level 1 dice have four summon crests** per die, **Level 2 have three**, **Level 3 have two**, and **Level 4 have one**. They all have other crests on the remaining sides.

Here is an image taken from the linked [ruling booklet](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/43575.pdf) that specifies what is the content of each face of each dice level:

[image]

In text:

- **Lvl 1 Dice (Red):** 4 Summon Crests, 1 Movement Crest, 1 (x2) Defense Crest
- **Lvl 2 Dice (Blue):** 3 Summon Crests, 1 (x2) Movement Crest, 1 (x2) Attack Crest, 1 Spell Crest
- **Lvl 3 Dice (Yellow):** 2 Summon Crests, 2 Movement Crests, 1 Attack Crest, 1 (x2) Trap Crest
- **Lvl 4 Dice (Green):** 1 Summon Crest, 1 (x2) Movement Crest, 1 Attack Crest, 1 Defense crest, 1 (x2) Spell Crest, 1 Trap Crest.

Comment: @Thunderforge there you go, included dice color. Source, the picture you linked on bgg :)